# Connect SPFx to an OOB SharePoint List webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-experience

I have this scenario. My page consists of two web parts:

- the first is standard Modern List web part;
- the second is SPFx web part

Based on a selected item in the first web part a user should be able to add a comment via the second web part and safe it to different SP List. Note that out of box commenting functionality does not suit our real scenario.

How can a selected item be passed to the SPFx web part? Key point here is that the first one is standard SP List web part.

I know that in case the first webpart is a SPFx web part the scenario can be implemented using Dynamic Data mechanism, Publisher / Subscriber pattern. However, we have then to provide our own render of the list and we lose the out of box list presentation and consistency. To replicate a standard Modern SharePoint list would be too much work.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Uk1DJxt6t0

Answer (score 1):

It appears that we can only connect:

- OOB webparts between each other. [See list here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/connect-web-parts-in-sharepoint-b457668c-d843-4b1b-8977-a6f9228a1dec?ns=spostandard&version=16&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=spo160&helpid=spo_connectwebparts&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#bkmk_listproperties).
- Two or more custom SPFx webpart.

However, there is no way to subscribe a custom SPFx webpart to the OOTB webparts. At least it's not officially described anywhere. I have a suspicion that with some hacking it can still be done, but it's not documented yet.

[Quote from https://docs.microsoft.com:](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/307847/how-can-we-connect-listwebpart-present-on-modern-p.html)

> For the OOB list, we cannot write custom code with it. You could use
> the OOB List properties web part to connect it.
>
> Refer to this documenatation for more:
> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/connect-web-parts-in-sharepoint-b457668c-d843-4b1b-8977-a6f9228a1dec?ns=spostandard&version=16&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=spo160&helpid=spo_connectwebparts&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#bkmk_listproperties