# SPFx Webpart as Source for List properties Webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-webparts, connected-web-parts

I wanted to know if it is possible to connect a custom SPFx Webpart to the List properties Webpart.

Since it is possible to connect two custom Webparts via DynamicData (as documented [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/sharepoint/dev/spfx/dynamic-data)) it seemed obvious to me that it would also possible to connect to an OOB Webpart if the Data is provided correctly.

But that is not the case because the List properties Webpart (or any OOB Webpart with a linkable Source) does not recognize my custom source.

An answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From my limited testing, the list/library webpart has it's own id hardcoded as the only acceptable source effectively killing any other connection possibilities. It's what killed a project of mine.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to connect custom SPFx web part with SharePoint OOTB web parts using dynamic data.

You can only connect two or more custom SPFx web parts using dynamic data.

**Similar questions**:

1. [Connect SPFx to an OOB SharePoint List webpart](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/292601/connect-spfx-to-an-oob-sharepoint-list-webpart)
2. [How to connect custom spfx web part to List web part using dynamic data?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/784393/how-to-connect-custom-spfx-web-part-to-list-web-pa.html)